# Right exactness of tensor product in a long exact sequence

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, flatness

Suppose that $$0\longrightarrow A\longrightarrow B\longrightarrow C\longrightarrow D\longrightarrow0$$ is an exact sequence of $R$-modules. Is it true that $$A\otimes M\longrightarrow B\otimes M\longrightarrow C\otimes M\longrightarrow D\otimes M\longrightarrow0$$ is exact by the right exactness of the tensor product? Here the module $M$ isn't assumed to be flat.

I think it is not true by breaking the original exact sequence into short exact sequences. So, does this hold?

Comment: Following your guess, try to find a counterexample.

Comment: If $0 \to B \to C \to D \to 0$ is exact, $0 \to 0 \to B \to C \to D \to 0$ is exact, too.